# MS ACCESS: How can i count distinct value using access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

here is the current complex query given below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Evaluation.ETCode, Training.TTitle, Training.Tcomponent, Training.TImpliment_Partner, Training.TVenue, Training.TStartDate, Training.TEndDate, Evaluation.EDate, Answer.QCode, Answer.Answer, Count(Answer.Answer) AS [Count], Questions.SL, Questions.Question
FROM ((Evaluation INNER JOIN Training ON Evaluation.ETCode=Training.TCode) INNER JOIN Answer ON Evaluation.ECode=Answer.ECode) INNER JOIN Questions ON Answer.QCode=Questions.QCode
GROUP BY Evaluation.ETCode, Answer.QCode, Training.TTitle, Training.Tcomponent, Training.TImpliment_Partner, Training.Tvenue, Answer.Answer, Questions.Question, Training.TStartDate, Training.TEndDate, Evaluation.EDate, Questions.SL
ORDER BY Answer.QCode, Answer.Answer;
```

There is an another column Training.TCode. I need to count distinct Training.TCode, can anybody help me?
If you need more information please let me know

Comment: please don't try to use count(distinct col), because MS Access doesn't support count(distinct). thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
select ..., count(distinct Training.Tcode) as ..., ...
```

**EDIT - please now look at this...**

Take the following SQL code. The first select is how SQL server would do this and the second  query should be access compliant...

```
declare @t table (eCode int, tcode int)
insert into @t values(1,1)
insert into @t values(1,1)
insert into @t values(1,2)
insert into @t values(1,3)
insert into @t values(2,2)
insert into @t values(2,3)
insert into @t values(3,1)    

select 
    ecode, count(distinct tCode) countof
from
    @t
group by
    ecode

select ecode, count(*)
from
    (select distinct tcode, ecode
    from  @t group by tcode, ecode) t
group by ecode
```

It returns the following:

```
ecode tcode
1       3 (there are 3 distinct tcode for ecode of 1)
2       2 (there are 2 distinct tcode for ecode of 2)
3       1 (there is 1 distinct tcode for ecode of 3)
```

Comment: sorry ignore me, I missed the ACCESS tag

Comment: Sorry brushing up on my access skills.... look here

http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

This shows that you can only do it count(distinct) by using two sub queries... Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadat, see my edited version. This should get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a similar question about a year ago in Google groups. I received an excellent answer:

---

A crosstab can do (from an original proposition from Steve Dassin) as long
as you count either the fund, either the subfund:

```
  TRANSFORM COUNT(*) AS theCell
  SELECT ValDate,
      COUNT(*) AS StandardCount,
      COUNT(theCell) AS DistinctCount
  FROM tableName
  GROUP BY ValDate
  PIVOT fund IN(Null)
```

which, for each day (group), will return the number of records and the
number of different (distinct)  funds.

Change

```
PIVOT fund IN(Null)
```

to

```
PIVOT subfund IN(Null)
```

to get the same, for sub-funds.

Hoping it may help,
Vanderghast, Access MVP

---

I don't know if that will work, but [here's a link to that post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.access.queries/browse_thread/thread/d79d1858a5880e9c/0ed6bd6c66e0ce2f#0ed6bd6c66e0ce2f).

Answer (score 2):

Sadat, use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Evaluation.ETCode, Training.TTitle, Training.Tcomponent, Training.TImpliment_Partner, Training.TVenue, Training.TStartDate, Training.TEndDate, Evaluation.EDate, Answer.QCode, Answer.Answer, Count(Answer.Answer) AS [Count], Questions.SL, Questions.Question,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Training t2 WHERE t2.TCode = Evalution.ETCode) as TCodeCount
FROM ((Evaluation INNER JOIN Training ON Evaluation.ETCode=Training.TCode) INNER JOIN Answer ON Evaluation.ECode=Answer.ECode) INNER JOIN Questions ON Answer.QCode=Questions.QCode
GROUP BY Evaluation.ETCode, Answer.QCode, Training.TTitle, Training.Tcomponent, Training.TImpliment_Partner, Training.Tvenue, Answer.Answer, Questions.Question, Training.TStartDate, Training.TEndDate, Evaluation.EDate, Questions.SL
ORDER BY Answer.QCode, Answer.Answer;
```

Comment: I was going to suggest making a view on the Training table complete with your count(*) as needed.  Then join on the VIEW version instead of the table directly.  This suggestion will do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do a count distinct value in Access by doing the following:

```
select Job,sum(pp) as number_distinct_fruits

from

(select Job, Fruit, 1 as pp

from Jobtable group by Job, Fruit) t

group by Job
```

You have to be careful as if there is a blank/null field (in my code fruit field) the group by will count that as a record. A Where clause in the inner select will ignore those though.
I've put this on my blog, but am concerned that I've discovered the answer too easily - others here seem to think that you need two sub queries to make this work. Is my solution viable? 
[Distinct groupings in Access](http://markfightscode.blogspot.com/2010/04/writing-count-distinct-query-in-ms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog entry,  it appears you can do this with subqueries....

http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would propose

```
select R_rep,sum(pp) as number_distinct_Billnos from (select R_rep, Billno, 1 as pp from `Vat_Sales` group by R_rep, Billno) t group by R_rep
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ETCode, t.TTitle, t.Tcomponent, 
      t.TImpliment_Partner, t.TVenue, t.TStartDate, 
      t.TEndDate, e.EDate, a.QCode, a.Answer, 
      q.SL, q.Question,
      Count(a.Answer) AnswerCount,
      Min(Select Count(*) 
       From (Select Distinct TCode From Training) As Z ) TCodeCount    
FROM Evaluation As e 
   JOIN Training AS t ON e.ETCode=t.TCode
   JOIN Answer AS a ON e.ECode=a.ECode
   JOIN Questions AS q ON a.QCode=q.QCode
GROUP BY e.ETCode, a.QCode, t.TTitle, t.Tcomponent, 
     t.TImpliment_Partner, t.Tvenue, a.Answer, q.Question, 
     t.TStartDate, t.TEndDate, Evaluation.EDate, q.SL
ORDER BY a.QCode, a.Answer;
```

Comment: i think you haven't tried it or didn't care about access database. in ms access count(distinct col) is not allowed, it throws syntax error as 'missing operator'

Comment: @Sadat, you are right, I'd forgotten how different Access SQL is... Then you will need a subquery instead... I've edited to include that

Comment: still this is not working. first of all you must explicitly use 'as' for alias. i have placed that, but still error is there.

Comment: @Sadat, I edited to add 'As's, and added an aggregate function around the subquery, But what error r u getting?

Comment: AS is not required for table aliases in Jet/ACE SQL, so I don't think that could be the cause of the problem.