# Microsoft Access From SQL Database Query Select Count Distinct Issue

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo_tblBidder.bidder_id) AS TotalRegistrants, 
    SUM(dbo_tblItem.item_premium + dbo_tblItem.item_pr) AS SumTotal, 
    dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type

FROM dbo_tblBidder LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_tblItem ON 
    dbo_tblItem.item_bidder_number = dbo_tblBidder.bidder_number AND 
    dbo_tblItem.item_sale_id = dbo_tblBidder.bidder_sale_id

WHERE (dbo_tblBidder.bidder_sale_id = 235)

GROUP BY dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type
```

When I try to execute this in MS Access, I am told:

```
Missing oporator 'COUNT(DISTINCT dbo_tblBidder.bidder_id)'
```

When I click on "OK", it highlights "dbo_tblBidder".  This query runs just fine on the SQL server, and I do not know what oporator MS Access believes is missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### UPDATE:

I actually had to try:

```
SELECT     Total.count, SUM(dbo_tblItem.item_premium + dbo_tblItem.item_pr) AS SumTotal, dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type
FROM         dbo_tblBidder LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo_tblItem ON dbo_tblItem.item_bidder_number = dbo_tblBidder.bidder_number   AND 
                  dbo_tblItem.item_sale_id = dbo_tblBidder.bidder_sale_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT     COUNT(bidder_type) AS count, bidder_type
                        FROM          dbo_tblBidder AS tblBidder_1
                        WHERE      (bidder_sale_id = 235)
                        GROUP BY bidder_type) AS Total ON dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type = Total.bidder_type
WHERE     (dbo_tblBidder.bidder_sale_id = 235)
GROUP BY dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type, Total.count
ORDER BY dbo_tblBidder.bidder_type
```

I'm waiting to hear back from the person trying to run it to see if this worked for them.

**UPDATE:**

This did not work.  Now, it tells me:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Then, it highlights "mber" from dbo_tblBidder.bidder_number where it says:

> dbo_tblItem ON dbo_tblItem.item_bidder_number = dbo_tblBidder.bidder_number

**ANSWERED:**

[MS Access to SQL query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892053/ms-access-to-sql-query-issue)

Comment: See whether this link is helpful to warn you about other differences between Access and SQL Server: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-the-main-differences-between-access-and-sql-server.html

Comment: @HansUp Thank you, that will be very helpful.  I'm actually new to SQL as well, coming from MySQL.  But having to then go to MS Access isn't very fun.  I appreciate the link. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access to SQL query issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892053/ms-access-to-sql-query-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Access does not support COUNT Distinct.  If you need that, you can try the trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412442/ms-access-how-can-i-count-distinct-value-using-access-query/1418762#1418762).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm not really sure what the commands in that query do, but I'm not so sure that can be implemented into what I need to do.  However, either way, I have updated my own query which works directly in SQL, and will see if MS Access likes it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Distinct` inside an aggregate function (the Count function).  Remove `distinct` and it should work fine.

If you still need a count of distinct bidder_IDs, I recommend pulling that in a separate query.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I do see now that MS Access does not like counting distincts.  However, removing it gave me incorrect counts, and I needed it within the same query.  But I rewrote my own query which works in SQL, and hopefully MS Access likes it as well.