# Using the MS Access COUNT DISTINCT function

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query returns the count of requests where AcquisitionDate is within 60 days of RequestDate, along with various other columns.

How can I modify the code to count the number of **unique** AcquisitionDates within 60 days of RequestDate? I tried to use COUNT DISTINCT but couldn't figure out how it should be used in this case.

```
SELECT SceneTable.PATH, SceneTable.ROW, SceneTable.ROW, SceneTable.UlLat,
       SceneTable.UlLon, SceneTable.UrLat, SceneTable.UrLon, SceneTable.LlLat, 
       SceneTable.LlLon, SceneTable.LrLat, SceneTable.LrLon, 
      Sum(Iif((DateDiff("d",[AcquisitionDate],[RequestDate])<60),1,0)) AS Expr1, 
       Count(RequestTable.RequestID) AS CountOfRequestID
FROM ((SceneTable INNER JOIN 
       SceneAcquisitionTable 
           ON SceneTable.SceneID = SceneAcquisitionTable.SceneID) INNER JOIN
       UserSceneAcquisitionTable 
           ON SceneAcquisitionTable.SceneAcquisitionID = 
              UserSceneAcquisitionTable.SceneAcquisitionID) INNER JOIN 
       RequestTable 
           ON UserSceneAcquisitionTable.UserSceneAcquisitionID = 
              RequestTable.UserSceneAcquisitionID
GROUP BY SceneTable.PATH, SceneTable.ROW, SceneTable.UlLat, SceneTable.UlLon, 
         SceneTable.UrLat, SceneTable.UrLon, SceneTable.LlLat, SceneTable.LlLon, 
         SceneTable.LrLat, SceneTable.LrLon
```

Here are sample tables as well as expected results:
[image: Here are sample tables as well as expected results:]

Comment: Which table holds AquisitionDate? You need to include a derived table or subquery `select distinct acquisitiondate from sometable` and count that. It may be a little more complicated, but that is the general idea.

Comment: @Remou SceneAcquisitionTable holds AcquisitionDate. I have tried this after the FROM statement and access complained about a syntax error:
    `AS A
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT AcquisitionDate FROM SceneAcquisitionTable)
    AS B
ON A.AcquisitionDate = B.AcquisitionDate`

Comment: That may not help with your count, even if you get it to work, because you will just end up with duplicates again. How do you want to count the date? For each item in group by? Because that is going to lead to a more complicated subquery or derived table. The easiest option might be to post a little sample data and an expected result.

Comment: @Remou I wish to consider the dates where acquisition-requested is < 60 and only the first occurrence of each acquisition date. There are a few variables to keep track of, so I have edited my post to include a sample of the tables being references and the expected output table.

Answer (score 0):

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418762/78522) about a generic way to implement COUNT DISTINCT in Access