# Issue Related to DISTINCT keyword in MS ACCESS Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MS ACCESS: How can i count distinct value using access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412442/ms-access-how-can-i-count-distinct-value-using-access-query)

I have database file in MSAccess Database..

I have used following query in ACCESS Database:

```
Select COUNT(Distinct(PRS.prs_personId)) From tb_personDepartment
```

but it gives error saying : `UnDefined function Distinct in expression`

i also tried following :

```
Select Distinct(COUNT(PRS.prs_personId)) From tb_personDepartment
```

it works but doesn't get disctinct PersonId from the datatable.

how can i use Distinct keyword with Count() function in MS ACCESS database ??

Thanks...

Comment: Your DISTINCT syntax is incorrect. MS Access is different from MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately MS Access does not allow you to use them at the same time (like `count(distinct yourCol)`, so you can use subquery:

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PRS.prs_personId
    FROM tb_personDepartment
)
```